# Moments of a Numpy Array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, math, physics

I have a numpy array, say

```
rho = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))
```

where each value represents the mass at that coordinate. I was a fast method to calculate the first 3 moments (so `sum rho(x,y) x^n y^m` for `m+n<=3` though I may need high values. My actual matrix is much larger. I can do it easily with for loops, so compute the mean, then subtract that in the following summations, but there must be an efficient way with numpy operations that I have not figured out. Is there a very easy way to do this?

Comment: I’m a bit confused by your notation in `sum rho(x,y) x^n y^m`.... are `rho(x,y)`, `x^n`, and `y^m` supposed to be multiplied together?

Comment: Show the loops so we have clear idea of what you want.

Comment: You can use `scipy.stats.moments`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.moment.html

Comment: @alkasm That is for [statistical moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)), not [physical moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(physics))